# Interacting with events and listeners in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to write GUI code that is orthogonal. Lets say I have a circle class and a square class and they need to interact. Right now, to get the circle and square talking to each other - say the circle object sends a message to the square object, I would use something like `square_obj.listen_for_circle(circle_obj)` where `listen_for_circle` is a method that implements an addlistener.

This is a problem for me since now the two objects are linked - and removing one object from my code would break it. What I am looking to do is for the circle_obj to be able to broadcast a global message say `'CIRCLE_EVENT'`. Additionally square_obj would be listening for global message broadcasts of type `'CIRCLE_EVENT'`, and upon hearing the event - does some action.(Ahhh, now the objects have no links to each other in the code base!)

Is this possible or even reasonable in MATLAB? (or maybe i'm just going crazy).
As always, advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure why ***addlistener*** is problematic for you. It basically just adds an event listener that doesn't do anything if the event-origin object (the circle) is deleted.

Alternately you can use ***event.listener*** or ***handle.listener***. They are undocumented but work well, and are widely used within the Matlab codebase (m-files). See explanation here: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/continuous-slider-callback/#Event_Listener

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The real problem is as my code-base gets larger for a particular project, more and more dependencies through listeners are created. Many GUI objects may have uses that are not critical and I may want to re-factor or remove them. This requires going through files and functions looking for dependencies, introduces bugs etc. My thinking is that if all my GUI components know exactly NOTHING about each other, but send a global message containing all relevant information when called, the code becomes much nicer as there are no dependencies anywhere

Comment: There is no "global event" in Matlab (AFAIK), but you can create a global general object and then have all your application components listen to events raised by that global object.